# Yii Many to Many Relational Query

Tags: yii, many-to-many, relational

Using a many many relational query with users having many clients and clients having many users. Trying to view a record of a particular client for a particular user. And if that client is not associated with that user, redirect to a different page.

```
// the relation in the client model
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
                'owners'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User','owner_client(owner_id, client_id)'),
                    );
}

//the relation in the user model
public function relations()
{


    return array(

        'clients'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Clients','owner_client(owner_id, client_id)'),
    );
}

//determine if user can view this client
//client record
        $client_record = Clients::model()->findByPk($id);
        //many query to find users
        $users =  $client_record->owners;

        //if user id is not found in array, redirect
        if (!in_array(Yii::app()->user->id, $users)) 
        {
           $this->redirect(array('/site/dashboard')); 
        }
```

The above code redirects, even though I know the client is related to the user logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$users =  $client_record->owners;`, what you're getting back is an array of all your user models that are associated with the current client.  As a result, you're comparing integers to objects, which means your in_array() condition will always fail.

What I recommend is that you build a conditional query to do your verification check.  Something like this should work:

```
$model = Clients::model()->with(
    array(
        'owners'=>array(
            'select'=>'owner_id',
            'condition'=>'user.id = '.Yii::app()->user->id,
        ),
    )
)->findByPk($id);

if ($model === null) {
    $this->redirect(array('/site/dashboard')); 
}
```

Comment: looks like the code Im looking for, but getting....Active record "User" is trying to select an invalid column "owner_id"

Comment: Actually, I just noticed something else.  My MANY_MANY declarations usually go like this:  `'A'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'A','B_A(A_id, B_id)'`.  I would've swapped `owner_id, client_id` to become `client_id, owner_id` in your Client model.

Comment: From where I got an understanding of MANY_MANY I noticed that was the only difference. But It's still same error

Comment: Can you confirm that your Client model has a field client_id and your User model has a field owner_id?  I'm starting to think that your original `$users =  $client_record->owners;` would've actually set $users to null.  Can you check that value and let me know what's in it?

Comment: Client model and user model doesnt have those fields. They both use id alone. client_id and owner_id are in the owner_client table

Comment: Oh, my bad!  I haven't played at this granularity in a long while.  I think you should be able to fix your problem simply by changing my "select" and "condition" from **owner_id** to **id**.  :)  I hope I haven't made any other blatant mistake.

Comment: getting different error.. Unknown columd 'owners.id.  getting close, because at the end of the error getting....WHERE (`t`.`id`='5') AND (owners.id = 14)

Comment: In the error, do you see `LEFT OUTER JOIN User owners`?  I created a similar query and it worked for me.  Can you paste the whole SQL query here so I can take a look?

Comment: Yes. Left Outer Join. I paste the whole error on the last line in my original question

Comment: Based on the error you posted, I'd change `owners.owner_id` to `user.id`.

Comment: Great!  Please mark this answer as correct if you can.  I'll also go back and clean up my answer to reflect the modifications we've made.